# How to read a SMS in iOS and is it able to pass an string to the application via link in the SMS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

do anybody know about how to read a SMS in iOS with Xamarin iOS ? and then I want to pass a string from that SMS to the application via link. For example when user click the link in the SMS it will pass a string value to the application and in the application a method is waiting to trigger that.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to read incoming or storing SMS's due to iOS security restriction.

Comment: This answer is invalid for iOS 12 and above versions. iOS 12 supports sms reading feature for OTP.

Comment: Not invalid, but obsolete. Proof please.

Answer (score 3):

Although you can't directly intercept SMS messages, you can create a [custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) so that if a user clicks a link in your message it will launch your app.

Answer (score 1):

If Jason's answer of using a link to the app, there is an alternative. In my case a web service is sending down a code (two stage auth). When I know its going to be coming, I prompt the user to looks for it, and when it comes long press the message bubble, and copy the whole message to the pasteboard.

When the user switches back to my app, I've set a flag to look at the pasteboard, I see the message, extract out the code, and if it "works" the user can continue without further interruption.

Not as elegant as Jason's answer, but if you cannot control the sms content, its an option.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible from iOS 12

```
textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

Please check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view) doc