# Tracking the load of SMS and phone calls

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get information about the number and length of SMSs sent by the phone's user (on iOS) and the same for regular phone calls?

The output of this would be something like: "Today you made 12 calls for 311 minutes, and sent 21 SMS messages."

I know there are spy apps that do that, and much more, but this is not what I'm looking for. My question is whether I can do this programmatically, within Apple's legit API.

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721041/how-to-read-a-sms-in-ios-and-is-it-able-to-pass-an-string-to-the-application-via/19723034#19723034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no API for that.

---

on jailbroken phones you could read the ams.app's & telephone's database

Comment: http://www.mspy.com/buynow.html?utm_expid=77466971-48.PiOcvobASCy8uwRkDaBT9A.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mspy.com%2Fno-jailbreak.html    How mspy does it?